# D3 Differencing chart: positive/negative colours not being shown

Tags: css, d3.js

I am trying to create a D3 differencing chart similar to this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3894205

I have taken much of the D3 and CSS3 code verbatim from the example and got the relevant lines and colour areas to be drawn when the user checks on a particular checkbox. However, my coding problem lies in that the areas above and below the splitting line are highlighted using the same colour, not the differencing colours defined in the CSS code.

The relevant CSS is below:

```
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
    /*  display: none;*/
    display: inline;
}

.area.above {
    fill: rgb(252,141,89);
    opacity:0.5;
}

.area.below {
    fill: rgb(145,207,96);
    opacity:0.5;
}

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

With the relevant D3 code taken and adapted for use from the example above is here:

```
dvc.line = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return main_x0(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return dvc.y(d[prelimLineArray]); });

dvc.area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) {return main_x0(d.date)})
    .y1(function(d) { return dvc.y(d[prelimLineArray]); }); 

dvc.focus.datum(dvc.data);

dvc.focus.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip-below")
    .append("path")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
    .attr("d", dvc.area.y0(dvc.height));

dvc.focus.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip-above")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", dvc.area.y0(0));

dvc.focus.append("path")
    .attr("class", "area above")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-above)")
    .attr("d", dvc.area.y0(function(d) {
    return dvc.y(d[selectedLineArray]);
}));

dvc.focus.append("path")
    .attr("class", "area below")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-below)")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
    .attr("d", dvc.area);
```

Can any help me and spot any errors in this code that would force only one CSS highlight colour to be used for both positive and negative graphed areas?

Thanks

Comment: I have some [familiarity](http://bit.ly/1pAEc9e) with diff charts but could not spot something that is obviously wrong. Could you generate a minimal fiddle or plunk? That would help...I recall having a similar issue when trying to apply a zoom brush to a diff chart. Otherwise, someone may be able to spot the problem based on the code above.

Comment: Thanks. I have since solved the problem. There seems to be an ambiguity in the CSS class naming. I found if I changed .area.below and .area.above to .areabelow and .areaabove respectively, in both the javascript/D£ script code and CSS it worked fine. Seems to be possible slight code discrepancy in Mike Bostock's example (I sat for ages trying other different things before finding this one). My <new> problem now lies in what this chap istry ing to solve: the positive/nagative differencing colours are n't brushing with the constraining lines I have drawn to bound the differencing area.